# ASP FileUpload with secondary iFrame submit only works once per page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe, file-upload

My goal is to get an file upload working on my web part using JS, jQuery and an iFrame so as to not require a page refresh. Here is my code

in ASP HTML page

```
<div class="DocumentUploader" id="DocumentUploader" style="position:relative">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:4px; left:6px"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litMultiChoiceDropDocument"></asp:Literal></div>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="fuMultiChoiceAddDocuments" AllowMultiple="true" onchange="DDPutDocument(); btnMultiChoiceAddDocuments.click()" BorderStyle="None" Width="100%" BackColor="Transparent" Style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; opacity:0; cursor:pointer" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="btnMultiChoiceAddDocuments" OnClick="btnMultiChoiceAddDocuments_Click" Style="display:none" />
</div>
```

and in Javascript

```
var hiddenIFrameID = "hiddenUploader";
function DDPutDocument() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    document.getElementById("aspnetForm").target = hiddenIFrameID;

    docsRefreshed = false;
    DDRefreshDocuments();
}

var docsRefreshed = false;
function DDRefreshDocuments() {
    if (!docsRefreshed) {
        DDLoadDocuments();
        setTimeout(DDRefreshDocuments, 2500);
    }
    else {
        var iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
        document.body.removeChild(iframe);
        document.getElementById("aspnetForm").removeAttribute("target");
    }
}
```

Walkthrough -

The `FileUpload` `onchange` event is triggered from the popup file dialog or from a file being dragged onto the `FileUpload` input. - works

The `onchange` method calls the javascript method first `DDPutDocument` and then invokes `btnMultiChoiceAddDocuments.click()`. - works

The `DDPutDocument` method creates an iFrame and assigns the target of the first form to be the iFrame, so that a submit action on the form will submit the iFrame, not the form.

The `btnMultiChoiceAddDocuments.click()` event submits the form, which is actually submitting the iFrame, and some codebehind for the button takes the file and saves it.

The `DDRefreshDocuments` method is called elsewhere, and it is being called correctly, the `else` statement in the method also gets called correctly and so should be handling my cleanup.

The problem -

This all works brilliantly for the first instance of uploading a file after the page load, the JS method executes, the button click event triggers a submit on the iFrame and the file is handled by the codebehind. When trying to upload a second file the JS method executes with no errors, carries into an infinite loop with attempting to refresh a list of documents (because the upload didn't work), but does not upload the file. Neither the `btnMultiChoiceAddDocuments_Click` event or the `Page_Load` event fire as they did in the first upload instance. The page needs to be reloaded in order to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same problem. For me it had to do with the cache.  How I fixed it was to return a value from the server after uploading.  This will refresh the server code. Or you can set the no-cache to the server back end.

This is my code behind inside a webapi(not sure if youre using a webapi, but you can get some ideas)

public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] FileAttachmentInfo fileAttachmentInfo)
         {
            //need to add user credential security here
            if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                HttpResponseMessage theResponse = null;

```
            string filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DCProfileFilePath"]);
            filepath += fileAttachmentInfo.DCId + "\\" + fileAttachmentInfo.Tab + "\\" + fileAttachmentInfo.Field + "\\" + fileAttachmentInfo.File;                

            //delete previous files and create File Path folder if not already created
            DeleteAndCreateFilePath(filepath);

            MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(filepath);

            var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

                var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
                {
                    var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
                    //return "File uploaded as " + info.FullName + " (" + info.Length + ")";
                    return info.Name;
                });
                return fileInfo;

            });

            // wait for task to complete. Not really async, is it?!
            task.Wait();
            // remove annoying header 
            theResponse.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Disposition");
            return theResponse;

        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "Invalid Request!"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer could use more detail (and examples)